# In touchdown PCR, should the extension temperature match the annealing temperature in phase 1?

Tags: pcr

For TD PCR, [it's recommended](https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2008.133) that the annealing temperature (T_a) be 10°C higher than the normal cycling T_a for the first 10 cycles or so, dropping 0.5 to 1.0°C/cycle. Should the extension temperature (T_ext) match this pattern to prevent miss-annealing? It seems that if the initial T_a was 75°C, then T_ext was set to 72°C (or whatever is optimal for the polymerase), the purpose of the high T_a would be lost.

Instead, should T_ext match T_a with an increased extension time until the optimal T_ext is reached?

Comment: Your initial annealing temperature 75°C would mean nomal cycling annealing temperature 65°C. That is really high. Is there a reason why you did not design your primers with Tm ~60°C (normal annealing ~55°C)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not if I understand correct the question. But I write you an example. For example for the amplification of the gene *nirS*, I used a touchdown PCR. The Tm of the primer is 60°C. I created a touchdown from 65°C and each cycle decrease of one degree (total cycle of the touchdown is 5). The thermoprofile is the following:
94°C for 3 min; 5 cycles of 94°C for 15 sec, 65°C (touchdown -1°C) for 30 sec, 72°C for 30 sec; 34 cycles of 94°C for 15 sec, 60°C for 30 sec, 72°C for 30 sec; followed for 72°C for 10 min.
Is better that in total your PCR do not make more than 40 cycles.
I hope that this help you
Jo